# How to apply multiple effect on GLSurfaceView in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, effects, glsurfaceview

Here is my code which works fine

```
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
        mEffect.setParameter("black", .9f);
        mEffect.setParameter("white", .5f);
        break;
```

but now I want two effects on it, what to do ?

```
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
        mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
```

I want to marge both effects with "grayscale image"

```
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also look at this documents but no help `[GLSurfaceView][1]`

[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html ,
 [EGLDisplay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html)

[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/EGLDisplay.html and [Effect factory too](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html)